# Xml etree failed to load external entity

Tags: python

I want to delete empty nodes in XML file and i have some errors.

I have tried to change etree.parse to ET.parse and add import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET but it still doesn't work.

script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import xml.etree.ElementTree
import sys
import os
from lxml import etree

notimportant_files = ['completed', 'README.md']

def main():
i = 0
names = []
for dir_file in os.listdir('../'):
    if dir_file == 'tools' or dir_file[0] == '.' or dir_file in notimportant_files:
        continue
    print('(%d) %s' % (i, dir_file))
    names.append(dir_file)
    i += 1
usr_numbers = int(input('Enter the number of the directory to parse from\n'))
if isinstance(usr_numbers, int):
    # Converting it to iterable as we may want to enter multiple directory we want to parse
    usr_numbers = [usr_numbers]
for usr_num in usr_numbers:
    dir_name = names[usr_num]
    loc_dir_name = dir_name.split('_')[0] + '_zap_' + dir_name.split('_')[1]
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        sys.argv.append('www.' + dir_name.split('_')[0].lower() + '.com')
    print('using %s as the host address' % (sys.argv[1]))
    file = 'zap_report_parsed.xml'
    
    Root = etree.parse('%s/zap_scans/%s/%s' % (os.path.expanduser('~'),loc_dir_name, file))
    for element in root.xpath(".//*[not(node())]"):
        element.getparent().remove(element)
    src = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
    filename = '../%s/report/zap_report_trimmed.xml' % (dir_name)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as output_file:
        output_file.write(src)
    
    del sys.argv[-1]
   
    print ('----------------------------')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

errors:

```
python3 /Users/username/Desktop/script.py
(0) xyz_scan
Enter the number of the directory to parse from
0
using www.xyz.com as the host address
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/script.py, line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/script.py", line 30, in main
    Root = etree.parse('%s/zap_scans/%s/%s' % (os.path.expanduser('~'),loc_dir_name, file))
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3536, in lxml.etree.parse
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1876, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1902, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1805, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1177, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 615, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 725, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 652, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
OSError: Error reading file '/Users/username/Desktop/zap_report_parsed.xml': failed to load external entity "/Users/username/Desktop/zap_report_parsed.xml"
```

Comment: You should probably show the file. It looks like it's referring to... itself? as an external entity.

Comment: Does /Users/username/Desktop/zap_report_parsed.xml actually exist? If it doesn't, then that OSError is what you get.

Comment: @mzjn you're right... I've changed path and almost working
I have one error now: NameError: name 'root' is not defined
Edit: capital letter.. done, thanks!!!